# CSS Transform Blurry Text

Tags: css

The following CSS renders the font blurry in chrome
How can I make my font unaffected?

```
.md-modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 630px;
    min-width: 320px;
    height: auto !important;
    z-index: 2000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); <This line
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); <-- This line
}
```

Comment: You'd have to demo it. It may just be the font you are using.

Comment: Its not the font its the transform

Comment: custom fonts & chrome != sharp crispy text

Comment: I fixed it by adding one pixel in the hight of the text wrapping container. IDK why it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to a number of reasons, often rectified by anchoring the z plane with `translateZ(0)`, to provide the item with its own composite layer - however a (combination of) the below may also procide results:

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0) translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Comment: Hey, adding this means the modal is no longer centered

Comment: @D-W....with the limited code you have in the question, Im afraid its a little hard to provide a precise answer, you will need to extend the transform property, not replace it with the above :S

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting an issue with rounding see the following article.

http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/gpu-text-rendering-in-webkit/

Try this.

```
function centerTarget(tar){
    var y = Math.ceil(tar.height()/2),
        x = Math.ceil(tar.width()/2);

    tar.css('transform','translateX(' + x + 'px) translateY(' + y + 'px)');
}
```

Where tar is a jquery object.

Whilst this isn't truly centered its within a pixel so that close enough for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Just my two cents.

```
transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(2, 2);
zoom: 0.5;
```

This works as long as you don't use `rem`'s in your css. Since scale increases size, rem unit gets also increased creating weird side effects.

Comment: Don't stop using REM because of this. Instead use flexbox to align your content. `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;`